# window.open not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova, google-chrome

developing a Cordova PhoneGap app and I try to pop up a window for facebook login after clicking a button. The popup works fine on iOS devices, but when debugging with Chrome, nothing happens, although popup-blocker are deactivated. (I'm a beginner in webdevelopment stuff and I could not find a proper solution for my problem searching for hours...)

```
$("#social_login_buttons").append('<p><a class="btn-auth btn-facebook large" href="#" onclick="fblogin.init()">' + localize.signInWith[common.lang] + '<b>Facebook</b></a></p>');


fblogin.init = function() {

    var authorizeUrl = fbAuthorizeUrl
    + "client_id=" + fbClientId
    + "&redirect_uri=" + fbRedirectUri
    + "&display=" + fbDisplay
    + "&response_type=token"
    + "&access_type=online"
    + "loginMethodName=loginWithFacebook"
    + "&scope=publish_stream,email";


    var me = this;
    var ref = window.open(authorizeUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,clearcache=yes');
 //code ommitted
}
```

Comment: `_blank` is an odd window name.

Comment: could be the chrome cross origin policy http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Comment: @ceejayoz _blank is opening a new window.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Huh, apparently `To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special value _blank for strWindowName.` That's a new one for me!

Comment: Yeah I get you. I don't know why he is doing it because it's by default window.open() opens a new window. I guess he just wants to re-insure that it opens a new window.  If you go here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp. It says he can do it but it is redundant.

Comment: I do the 'blank' because it's documented that way in PhoneGAP API http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open

Answer (score 0):

it's a security issue. chrome doesn't let scripts to open new window. the only way is to do it as a part of user action like a click.